# How to configure which Windows network interface WSL2 uses

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

We have VLANs configured with firewall rules. When I use WSL (version 2) it correctly uses the VLAN ip from cable interface and allow required connections, lets say: ssh.

But, I have a WIFI adapter too, and if I turn on HotSpot on Windows (Windows 10), WSL starts to use something different that can't reach services.

Normally my WIFI is turned off, but when I turn hotspot on it also turns WIFI on. No WIFI network is automatically connected. I tried only with WIFI on, and it works flawless.

The output from `ip link` or `ip route` do not change on WSL terminal. Output changes I have when I turn hotspot on:

- `lsof -i -P -n` shows `SYN_SENT`
- `ping` doesn't works
- `traceroute` is blocked by firewall, but it shows 1 line less, with last line on my Windows host

I can't find what it is doing wrong. Maybe using an IPv6 when our rules are based on IPv4? But on firewall logs nothing is shown, like if connection never leaves Windows host.

---

Output from `traceroute`. Line 3 and beyond is blocked. Line 2 isn't shown with hotspot on.

```bash
$ traceroute service
traceroute to service (10.6.124.158), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  windowshost.domain (172.23.48.1)  0.219 ms  0.212 ms  0.202 ms
 2  10.6.66.2 (10.6.66.2)  0.874 ms  1.330 ms  1.024 ms
 3  * * *
```

---

Output from `lsof`. Only status is changed.

```bash
$ lsof -i -P -n
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     2204   user    3u  IPv4  30814      0t0  TCP 172.23.53.53:55612->10.6.124.158:22 (SYN_SENT)
```

---

Output from `ip`. Nothing changes.

```bash
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:d4:a2:d6:59:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:65:bd:17:6e:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:f5:05:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

---

Output from `route print -4` on Windows. Some active routes are added (*).

```
===========================================================================
Rotas ativas:
Endereço de rede          Máscara   Ender. gateway       Interface   Custo
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.6.66.1       10.6.66.33    281
        10.6.66.0    255.255.255.0      No vínculo        10.6.66.33    281
       10.6.66.33  255.255.255.255      No vínculo        10.6.66.33    281
      10.6.66.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo        10.6.66.33    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
      172.23.48.0    255.255.240.0      No vínculo       172.23.48.1   5256
      172.23.48.1  255.255.255.255      No vínculo       172.23.48.1   5256
    172.23.63.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo       172.23.48.1   5256
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0      No vínculo      192.168.56.1    281
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255      No vínculo      192.168.56.1    281
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo      192.168.56.1    281
    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0      No vínculo     192.168.137.1    281 *
    192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.137.1    281 *
  192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.137.1    281 *
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo        10.6.66.33    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo     192.168.137.1    281 *
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      No vínculo       172.23.48.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo        10.6.66.33    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo     192.168.137.1    281 *
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      No vínculo       172.23.48.1   5256
===========================================================================
```

Comment: WSL2 traffic is routed by the host – does the output of `route -4 print` on Windows change in any way?

Comment: Yep @user1686, it changes. Added on question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Hyper-V Manager tools:

1. Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>;
2. Type "optionalfeatures" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
3. Search "Hyper-V" and check the checkbox;
4. Hit "OK" and restart computer.

---

PS. I don't know why this solved my problem, so I'm putting this answer as community wiki if someone wants to improve it.